# Remove part from the Url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I ve looked into many examples in stackoverflow and couldn't find a working solution for me.

I have a wordpress blog set up in a subdirectory.

The blog sits under www.domain.co.uk/wordpress/

In order for my permalinks to work I did an htaccess rewrite rule which is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://domain.co.uk/wordpress [L]
```

Is there a way to take out the `/wordpress` part on the URL? 
I need it to point there but I want the `/wordpress` to be removed.
Any ideas?

I have now managed to solve this issue following this guide: http://www.optiniche.com/blog/145/wordpress-tutorial-install-wordpress-in-a-different-directory/

Comment: I think you can do that in *General Settings*. In this case, modify the **Home** URL to point to root. Check this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for replying... that didnt work either :(

Comment: Yes I give the solution at my last comment... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the wordpress from the redirect in your rule (the `http://domain.co.uk/` means there's an implicit redirect) and add a specific rule to internally rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.co.uk/ [L,R=301]

# now silently rewrite to wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi thank for replying...It came back with this error: 
Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web1/user43392/website/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:') in /web1/user43392/website/index.php on line 17

Comment: I have now managed to solve this following this guide http://www.optiniche.com/blog/145/wordpress-tutorial-install-wordpress-in-a-different-directory/